# Twitter api getting unauthorized

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to use the twitter API to follow other users, the endpoint uses Oauth 1.0 [Link to Docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/follows/api-reference/post-users-source_user_id-following#tab0), I'm using the twitter-v2 nodejs library to make the request, which handles the auth part.

```
var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'hidden',
    consumer_secret: 'hidden',
    access_token_key: 'hidden',
    access_token_secret: 'hidden'
      });
const makeReq = async () => {
    
    const { data } = await client.post('users/:id/following', {target_user_id: 'id' });


}
makeReq()
```

I keep getting 401 unauthorized error , but if I try the same request in postman with the same credentials, the request went through with no issue.

Comment: where have you added the authorization header?

Comment: @DaImTo I used twitter-v2 library for the auth part, https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-v2 .

Comment: @DaImTo I console logged the auth header generated by the library.

'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="UdRvhqCInYBvv3fOmE2TkgKiF", oauth_nonce="55n5RoVao22SBJv88K2rB9kqL4NBjKr0", oauth_signature="SWMamn2t0QJ0Zl1ETmgUHLLQI%2BI%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1623928966", oauth_token="1402633854628761607-fEEYrBryPUwMfckKVS7FSFsw1PCZ9S", oauth_version="1.0"'

Comment: Is the app you are using inside of a Project on the Twitter Developer Portal? It must be in a project for access to the v2 API.

Comment: @AndyPiper Yes it is in a project. It was probably something wrong with the tweeter-v2 library, I switched to twitter V1.1 API, and it works fine now.